# Using jenkins variables in mutline shells

Tags: shell, jenkins

Given the following script:

```
node {
  def hello = "Hello"
  stage("Greetings") {
    echo "${hello}world!"
  }
}
```

The logs display **HelloWorld!**

When I attempt to use this in a multi-line sh command

```
node {
  def hello = "Hello"
  stage("Greetings") {
    sh '''
     echo ${hello}world!
    '''
  }
}
```

The variable is regarded as an empty string resulting in **world!**

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using double quotes instead of single quotes. Try this, see if this will work.

```
node {
  def hello = "Hello"
  stage("Greetings") {
      sh """
        export GREETINGS=5
        echo ${hello}world \$GREETINGS times!
      """
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I updated your answer so that it also covers a use-case with an environment variable